# What does $\langle T\rangle^⊥$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

"Show that $T^\bot = \langle T\rangle ^\bot$"
Can someone explain what '$\langle T\rangle^\bot$ means, I understand $T^\bot$ and hopefully when I have the definition I will be able to do the question myself. Thanks

Hey sorry for some reason this isn't letting me add comments today, this was in relation to orthogonal complements, thanks vadim123 that was the answer I was looking for. Will try and up your answer when it lets me again.

Comment: You should be more precise. What is T? It might simply be you have to show that the ortogonal to a set coincides with the ortogonal to ist span.

Comment: It depends. What is $T$? What is $\langle T\rangle$? What is the context? Are you dealing with orthogonal complements?

Answer (score 2):

$T$ denotes a (possibly finite) set of vectors.  $\langle T \rangle$ denotes the vector space spanned by $T$, a (typically infinite) set of vectors.

$T^\perp$ denotes those vectors orthogonal to each element of $T$, while $\langle T\rangle^\perp$ denotes those vectors orthogonal to each element of the span of $T$.